# Dynamically Create Boxes

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

**The Challenge:**

Draw a rectangle of ASCII boxes: []

**The Rules:**

Takes a width and a height input

You can assume both of these are numbers

Must produce a string with newline characters, \n

**Examples:**

2, 2:

```
[][]
[][]
```

2, 3:

```
[][]
[][]
[][]
```

Fewest Bytes wins.

Comment: Nice first post! Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Can I assume that the numbers are positive? Can there be trailing newlines?

Comment: @dzaima Positive integers, no trailing or leading stuff

Comment: can we print to console or do we need to return the string?

Comment: @MDXF Thanks! (filler)

Comment: @Giuseppe return the string

Comment: what if we literally can't not print trailing newlines? it tends to be good practice to allow one trailing newline

Comment: I'll accept it, but it's better without the trailing newline for this purpose

Comment: @Robinlemon you might want to wait before accepting an answer, if you accept an answer than people are less inclined to answer

Comment: @StephenS, Sorry, first post! =) Thanks for the heads up, I've unaccepted an answer now!

Comment: @Robinlemon no problem :) usually you'd wait until it's been up a week or so, the top answer currently will probably win but it's possible someone might pull something crazy. Nice challenge for your first one :)

Comment: Nice 1st challenge. A couple of points: 1. It's not clear from the spec or examples whether the rectangle should be filled or just an outline. People interpreted it as filled because that's easier, but in future you should consider the spec more carefully. Writing a good challenge is hard - you can post to our sandbox before feedback before posting on the main site https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/15599 2. trailing newline should be either OK or not OK. Least bytes is better. if I can do it shorter with trailing newline, saying "No trailing newline is better"  is a contradiction.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Thanks for the tips, I do agree I did contradict myself, it was supposed to be filled and I didn't really think of that perspective! Will definitely use the sandbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
Ƨ[]*∙
```

Simple:

```
Ƨ[]    push "[]"
   *   multiply horizontally (repeating width times)
    ∙  get an array with input (height) items of that
       implicitly output the array joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 26 bytes

```
Grid@Table["[]",{#2},{#}]&
```

Comment: Does a Mathematica `Grid` object count as "a string with newline characters"?

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
v&DiiX"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v0zNJTMzQun/f2MuIwA)

#### Explanation

```
v    % Concatenate the (non-existing) stack contents: gives []
&D   % String representation: gives '[]'
ii   % Take two inputs
X"   % Repeat those numbers of times vertically and horizontally. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - <s>7</s> 5 bytes

-2 bytes by a clever trick thanks to insert_name_here

```
VE*`Y
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VE%2a%60Y&input=8%0A4&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
VE*`Y
V      # Loop
 E     # <input> number of times
   `Y  # String representation of empty list (used to be "[]", but insert_name_here pointed out this shorter alternative)
  *    # repeat string implicit input number of times
       # implicit print
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by using `\`Y` (string representation of empty list) instead of `"[]"`.

Comment: @insert_name_here Ingenious!! I updated the answer.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Came up with this exact code independently. Nicely done.

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
f(w,h){for(h*=w;h--;)printf(h%w?"[]":"[]\n");}
```

or

```
f(w,h){for(h*=w;h--;)printf("[]%c",h%w?0:10);}
```

My first code golf attempt, did I miss anything obvious?

Comment: There's this for 45, but it has a newline at the beginning: `f(w,h){h*=w;while(h--)printf("\n[]"+!(h%w));}`

Comment: That only works when width is 2.

Comment: So it does, my mistake

Comment: Great first golf! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Wouldn't using a `for` loop shorten the code even more?

Comment: @CoolGuy updated, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
F„[]×,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f7VHDvOjYw9N1/v834TIGAA)

**Explanation**

Input takes as `height, width`

```
F         # height times do
 „[]      # push "[]"
    ×     # repeat width times
     ,    # print with newline
```

Answer (score 3):

## [;#+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/shp), 197 bytes

```
>;;;;;;~++++++++:>~;;;;:>~*(-:~<~+-::>-:::<~<-+++++++++~:::<~+-:::>-::*)-::<-::::>-::(;)::>-::*(-:~<~+-::>-:::<~<-+++++++++~:::<~+-:::>-::*)-:<~<;;;;;-+>-:<-:-(-:::~<-:::(~<#<-;;-#~;)-:<#-::<;>-:-)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY4xDsAgDAP5C0sgytJuIeI9HSt199dpEtEHNBJE9lmG57rXmiMHvEcnQvvqJAoDi@r0owaTL8VII1jC3vyyUClptO3/7HCe3xF2x/uEgiKbCVZNnFWMiNZ4cnhO2lpnOcoL) Requires a zero byte after each input number.

I kinda don't know how this works. What I can tell you is that this part of the code:

```
 *(-:~<~+-::>-:::<~<-+++++++++~:::<~+-:::>-::*)-::<-::::>-::(;)::>-::*(-:~<~+-::>-:::<~<-+++++++++~:::<~+-:::>-::*)
```

is parsing the input numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## brainfuck, 145 bytes

```
+++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>+[>+>+<<-]>>++>,>+++++++++[<----->-]<--->>>,>+++++++++[<----->-]<--->++++++++++<[<<<[>+>+<<-]>[<<<.>.>>-]>[<<+>>-]>>.<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwai7eBMbRvdWDuQgJ22DYgJlLHTQUhH2@iCgJ1uLIhhZ4dHDsnIaBsbG4SRIJ6enZ6dHYStDWbY6QGluP7/NzUFAA)

My first ever code golf! Yay!

The input is in ascii + 48, so in order to do 50, 50 you must input b, b (the ascii letters for 98)

### Explanation

```
+++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>+ Get the opening square bracket into first position
[>+>+<<-] Get it into the second and third position
>>++ Get the third position to be the closing bracket
>
,>+++++++++[<----->-]<--- Get first number into fourth cell
>>>
,>+++++++++[<----->-]<--- Get second number into seventh cell
>++++++++++ get newline into 8th position
<

[ Start our height loop
<<<[>+>+<<-] Get the width into the fifth and sixth positions
>[ Start our width loop at the fifth position
<<<.>. Print the second and third positions
>>-] Decrement the fifth position
>
[<<+>>-] copy the sixth position into the fourth position
>>. print newline
<-]
```

Comment: Impressive. Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: Why is the input ASCII+48? You can save a lot of bytes by just using ASCII+0 input (possibly linking to the ASCII+48 version for usability)

Comment: I just wanted to meet the criteria for input, @calculatorFeline

Comment: ...Oh right. :|

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
'[]'$~],+:@[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcoxC8IwFATgPb/iECEWY0yjLimCKDiJg2vpEEJKq8UWEx396/G1yHGP4/Hd00zyGnsDLqBgqCuJ001czomXFZ9/K7E0hzJlLLqRaUpB3dBVlAL59NliN26FnF2PEu1zeEdoAW2Yd02Pek14aN0D0U2i//gXbNch@hDhbPDhTxdCEvfWNRnh9AM)

### Explanation

```
'[]'$~],+:@[   input: y, x
        +:@[   double y
      ],       pair with x
               this gives (x, 2y)
    $~         shape the left argument into the right argument's shape
'[]'           2-length character string
```

This gives us an `x` by `2y` string of repeating `[]` characters.

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcoxC8IwFATgPb/iECEWY0xbXVJcFJzEwTV0CCGl1WKLiY7@9fha5LjH8fjuaSF5g4MGF1DQ1I3E6SYu58RNzZffWpi1SRmLblIFpaKWdBWlQj5/dthPWyFn16NE9xzfEYVAoZl37YBmS3js3APRzWL4@Bds3yP6EOFs8OFPV0IS99a1GeH0Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7, 32 bytes

Full program:

```
n,m=input()
exec"print'[]'*n;"*m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P08n1zYzr6C0REOTK7UiNVmpoCgzr0Q9OlZdK89aSSv3/38jHWMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ẋ⁾[]ẋ$Y
```

A dyadic link returning a list of characters (or a full program printing the result).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hru5HjfuiY4G0SuT///@N/hsDAA)**

#### How?

```
ẋ⁾[]ẋ$Y - Main link: number w, number h          e.g. 2, 3
ẋ       - repeat w h times                            [2,2,2]
     $  - last two links as a monad:
 ⁾[]    -   literal ['[',']'],                        "[]"
    ẋ   -   repeat list (vectorises)                  ["[][]","[][]","[][]"]
      Y - join with newlines                          "[][]\n[][]\n[][]"
        - if a full program, implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 25 Bytes

```
param($w,$h),("[]"*$w)*$h
```

-3 thanks to Mathias!

Comment: You can shorten it to 25 like so: `param($w,$h),("[]"*$w)*$h`

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>13</s> 12+1= <s>14</s> 13 bytes

+1 for the `-R` flag.

```
"[]"pN× òU*2
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=IltdInBO1yDyVSoy&input=NSw2Ci1S)

- 1 byte saved thanks to obarakon.

Comment: Being a little drunk can [sometimes help your programming skills](https://xkcd.com/323/) though :P

Comment: @ETHproductions: the very cartoon I was looking for but was too drunk to find!

Comment: Haha, hope you guys are having a fun night. fyi, `U*V` can be shortened to `N×`

Comment: @obarakon: That's 2 opportunities to work with `N` last night. Never drink & golf, kids!

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 32 bytes

```
.+
$*
1(?=1*(¶1+))|.
$1
G`1
1
[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLUMPe1lBL49A2Q21NzRo9LhVDLvcEQy5DrujY//@NuYwA) Takes height and width input on separate lines.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
ＥＮ×[]Ｉη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDDM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU0chJDM3tVhDKTpWSUfBObG4RCNDU1PT@v9/Iy7j/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order height, width. Charcoal's drawing primitives aren't suited to this, so this just takes the easy way out and repeats the `[]` string appropriately. Explanation:

```
 Ｎ      First input as a number
Ｅ       Map over implcit range
      η Second input
     Ｉ  Cast to number
   []   Literal string
  ×     Repeat
        Implicitly print on separate lines
```

Comment: Well it has drawing primitives for this but [still 8 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98/KSc/L10jJDM3tVjDSEfBM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDUxONr6OgFB2rpPn/vxGX8X/dsv@6xTkA) :P

Comment: @ASCII-only Sorry, I didn't realise that Oblong worked on arbitrary strings. Neat!

Comment: @ASCII-only Oh, and what's the verbose name of the predefined empty string variable?

Comment: It's `w`, [name](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/blob/master/charcoal.py#L331), [greek to verbose](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/blob/master/codepage.py#L18)

Comment: @ASCII-only Then what am I doing wrong here: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU@jXEchSdP6////umX/dYtzAA "Charcoal – Try It Online")

Comment: Oops sorry for some reason I left out `w` in the parser, will fix ASAP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59844/discussion-between-ascii-only-and-neil).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda n,m:('[]'*n+'\n')*m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9dKQz06Vl0rT1s9Jk9dUyv3f0FRZl6JRpqGkY6xpuZ/dWVlBSAEkepcxgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 7 bytes

```
Ài[]<esc>ÀÄ
```

where `<esc>` is `0x1b`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3BDZnSs9OGGwy3///83@W8KAA)

#### Explanation

```
Ài[]<esc>                    " arg1 times insert []
         ÀÄ                  " arg2 times duplicate this line
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 9 bytes

```
M"[]"┘ÄJ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f/fVyk6VunRlBmHW7x0/v834jIGAA)

#### Explanation

```
M"[]"┘ÄJ,
M         //Executes code input1 times
 "[]"     //Pushes []
     ┘Ä   //Duplicates [] input2 times
       J  //Joins the stack
        , //Prints with a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

```apl
'[]'⍴⍨⊢,2×⊣
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@lR2wT16Fj1R71bHvWueNS1SMfo8PRHXYv//zdSSFIw4jIGkQA)

`'[]'` the string

`⍴⍨` cyclically repeated to fill the shape

`⊢` right argument (rows)

`,` and

`2×` twice

`⊣` the left argument (columns)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 55 bytes

```bash
seq $(($1*$2))|sed s/.*/[]/|tr -d "
"|fold -w $(($1*2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEFFQ0PFUEvFSFOzpjg1RaFYX09LPzpWv6akSEE3RUGJS6kmLT8nRUG3HKoSqPD////G/00A) Uses the TIO flavor of bash, since I run windows.

Comment: I don't think this works for multi-digit numbers

Comment: @KritixiLithos It should work now

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

6 bytes of code, +1 for the `-R` flag.

```
VÆç"[]
```

Doesn't work in the latest version due to a bug with `ç`, but it does work in [commit `f619c52`](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/tree/f619c52d28277eaf279903146e832360384acb02). [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=f619c52d28277eaf279903146e832360384acb02&code=VsbnIltd&input=MiAzIC1S)

#### Explanation

```
VÆ   ç"[]
VoX{Uç"[]"}  // Ungolfed
             // Implicit: U, V = input integers
VoX{      }  // Create the range [0...V) and replace each item X with
    Uç"[]"   //   U copies of the string "[]".
-R           // Join the result with newlines.
             // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 70 bytes

```r
p=paste
function(w,h)p(rep(p(rep('[]',w),collapse=''),h),collapse='
')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8C2ILG4JJUrzTatNC@5JDM/T6NcJ0OzQKMotUADQqpHx6rrlGvqJOfn5CQWFKfaqqtrApUg8WPy1DX/p2kY65hocqVpGOkYaf4HAA)

Returns an anonymous function that constructs and returns the string.

### 45 bytes, non-conforming

```r
function(w,h)write(matrix('[]',w,h),'',w,,'')
```

An anonymous function that prints out the string in the desired format.

[Try this online](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jXCdDs7wosyRVIzexpCizQkM9OlZdBySqow6igaTm/zQNYx0TTa40DSMdI83/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 74 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func(x,y int)string{return Repeat(Repeat("[]",x)+"\n",y)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDBasQwDETv/orBp3gbNrC9FfoPpde2B69jB9NYDrYMG5b99qyTlFJoTxUCwQyMnjTEZdLmUw8WQXsSojvAxN7C5zpDsMS2x9kaXXIVedU11Y40h1gyXCHDPtLiwxQTH2Xm5GnIUqxOc2lneGK1q9dkuSTCq52s5uZryLcP2V7Ug3wn2c7qthw6IfY4SBdYoutAkVER@poGbbjoceNsEWmc4WIC28x1h/gFspFs5zUKV4FaDk/P@DfgypN1sN/Hg2P90c73E2XfFfj4UsN5pMY1pxYnpf42HqtxW@4)

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 14 bytes

```
[:|?[:|?@[]`';
```

Explanation:

```
[:|     FOR a = 1 to (read input from cmd line)
?       PRINT a newlne
[:|     FOR c = 1 to (read input from cmd line)
?@[]`   PRINT A$ (containing the box)
';         and inject a semicolon in the compiled QBasic code to suppress newlines
```

This takes its arguments in the order of #rows, #cols. Output starts with a newline.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>43</s> 36 bytes

From the comments, a trailing newline is now permitted.

```
w=>h=>("[]".repeat(w)+`
`).repeat(h)
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
w=>h=>("[]".repeat(w)+`
`).repeat(h)
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)(+j.value);o.innerText=f(i.value=2)(j.value=2)
```

```css
*{font-family:sans-serif;}
input{margin:0 5px 0 0;width:50px;}
```

```html
<label for=i>w: </label><input id=i type=number><label for=j>h: </label><input id=j type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 8 bytes

```
}A;**"[]
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7DA%3B%2a%2a%22%5B%5D&input=5%0A3)

Also 8 bytes:

```
 F2K*"[]
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=+F2K%2a%22%5B%5D&input=5%0A3)

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 78 bytes

```
(w,h)=>"".PadLeft(h).Replace(" ","".PadLeft(w).Replace(" ","[]")+'\n').Trim();
```

[Run in C# Pad](http://csharppad.com/gist/333b511ae47260be12c20bea40d4981c)

This is shorter than with for-loops and I'm not aware of any function in C# which can repeat with less code.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 10 bytes

```
l~"[]"*N+*
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
,./@$'[]'"0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0FHT99BRT06Vl3J4H9qcka@QpqCqYIhF5RppGAMYxoqmPwHAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
[]×＊
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTVCJTVEJUQ3JXVGRjBB,i=MiUwQTM_,v=7)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
ƛk[⁰*
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%C6%9Bk%5B%E2%81%B0*&inputs=4%0A5&header=&footer=)

Takes height then width.

-1 thanks to lyxal.

```
ƛ      # map 0...(height) to...
 k[    # `[]`
    *  # repeated...
   ⁰   # (width)
    *  # times
       # (j flag) join by newlines
```

Comment: [5 bytes (dw, you didn't miss the `k[` constant ;p)](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%C6%9Bk%5B%E2%81%B0*&inputs=4%0A5&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 50 bytes

```
proc B w\ h {time {puts [string repe {[]} $w]} $h}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFJoTxGIUOhuiQzN1WhuqC0pFghurikKDMvXaEotQAoFB1bq6BSDiIyav87KRgpGHGBVekiAy6QhPF/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## R, 49 bytes

```
s=scan;cat(rep(c(rep("[]",s()),"\n"),s()),sep="")
```

**Ungolfed :**

```
s=scan # Creates an alias for the scan function

cat( # Prints to STDOUT
    rep( # The repetion of the following string :
        c(rep("[]",s()),"\n"), # "[]" repeated the number of times inputed by the user, followed by a linebreak
    s()), # This number of time (again, user inputed)
sep="") # with no separator
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 19 bytes

```perl
say for('[]'x<>)x<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhLb9IQz06Vr3Cxk4TiP//N@Iy/pdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0AAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 31 bytes

```sh
repeat $1 S+=[]
repeat $2 <<<$S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqJgpGD8vyi1IDWxREHFUCFY2zY6lgvGN1KwsbFRCf7/HwA)