# Make me a fence!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

### Challenge

This is a simple challenge. Given **two positive integers** `w` and `h` create an ASCII fence with a width of `w` and a height of `h`. The fence should be constructed using the following rules:

- The `+` character will represent a post.
- The `-` character will be used to represent the width of the fence.
- The `|` will be used to represent the height of the fence.
- After *exactly* three `-` characters have been outputted, a `+` character *must* be outputted afterward. Excluding the four corners, any other time you output a `+` would be invalid. You are allowed to follow this rule starting either from the left or the right (see examples), but you must be consistent.
- After *exactly* two `|` characters have been outputted, a `+` character *must* be outputted afterward. Excluding the four corners, any other time you output a `+` would be invalid.  You are allowed to follow this rule starting either from the top or bottom (see examples), but you must be consistent.
- Each fence will have exactly four corners, and each corner will be represented with a `+`.

In other words: At every three `-` characters, you must output a `+`. And at every two `|` characters, you must output a `+`.

You can assume that the fence will **always** be a rectangle, and that both `w` and `h` will never be greater than `100` or less than `1`. Trailing and/or preceding whitespace is allowed.

### Examples/Test Cases

```
w = 1
h = 1

+-+ 
| |
+-+


w = 3
h = 2

+---+
|   |
|   |
+---+


w = 5
h = 7

+---+--+ or +--+---+
|      |    |      |
|      |    +      +
+      +    |      |
|      |    |      |
|      |    +      +
+      +    |      |
|      |    |      |
|      |    +      +
+      +    |      |
|      |    |      |
+---+--+    +--+---+

w = 10
h = 5

+---+---+---+-+  or +-+---+---+---+
|             |     |             |
|             |     +             +
+             +     |             |
|             |     |             |
|             |     +             +
+             +     |             |
|             |     |             |
+---+---+---+-+     +-+---+---+---+


w = 4
h = 4

+---+-+ or +-+---+
|     |    |     |
|     |    |     |
+     +    +     +
|     |    |     |
|     |    |     |
+---+-+    +-+---+
```

### Rules

- [Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124276/dynamically-create-boxes)

Comment: Am I right to understand there may not be two `+`'s touching?

Comment: @xnor Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Great first challenge, by the way.

Comment: @StephenS Thanks. I'll remember that. Also since I'm here, how long do you guys usually wait before accepting an answer? I don't want to annoy anyone be waiting to long or not waiting long enough before selecting an answer.

Comment: Does the 6 bullet points mean that a `+` symbol can be inserted between **every** two `-`?

Comment: @ChristianDean in other words, can the top line be `+-+-+-+-+-+`?

Comment: @ChristianDean but `+-+-+-+-+-+` violates none of your 6 rules.

Comment: @LeakyNun Your right. That's a case I didn't have in mind when making my rules. I added a rule to state why `+-+-+-+-+-+` is invalid. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can I choose whether to output `+---+-+` or `+-+---+`? Can I output different strings on the top and bottom, as long as the three `-` rule is applied?

Comment: Your last rule doesn't make sense, "at least 3" isn't right, since we certainly can't have *more* than 3. Did you mean something like "as many segments as possible must be of length 3"?. (For example: if w=4, this would make `+---+-+` and `+-+---+` valid options, but `+--+--+` and `+-+-+-+-+` invalid). Or did you mean you should only add the minimum number of extra posts (which would make `+--+--+` valid but `+-+-+-+-+` invalid)?

Comment: @ChristianDean Thanks for clarifying. Don't forget you can work these clarifications into the premise of the question, too ("posts cost money and time to dig, so you want to minimize the number of extra posts, but fence lengths can't be longer than...").

Answer (score 9):

## C, 131 bytes

```
#define L for(i=0,j=w;j;)putchar(i++%4?--j,45:43);puts("+")
f(w,h,i,j,c){L;for(j=1;h;printf("%c%*c\n",c,i,c))c=j++%3?--h,124:43;L;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3RCoJAEEXf/YphQ9jNEdxcCRqkH/ATepGpzV3IogwfxG@3CerJ@zZnLudyfmVels354kN/gQb8/alDXWCsR4pkHu@Bu1ZQlqXumOcRXXVwpSF5vLTKlEm8HrHDgBHZTA19BbG21NHjGfrBa5VyuuVTr5ClxcZwHcVWiq1Du3Oio4bmRcpwa0OvTTIlIPHaItj/lDL0oyXCbk0rhP2a2gKhWmOH4OSYlw8)

**Explanation:**

```
// The first and the last line are always similar, so let's use a macro
// to avoid code duplication.
#define L

// Let's initialize 'i' and 'j'. 'i' will be used to keep track of which
// character ('+' or '-') we should print, whereas 'j' starts from the
// input width and the loop terminates when 'j' reaches zero.
for(i=0,j=w;j;)

// We post-increment 'i' and take a modulo 4 of its previous value.
// If i%4 == 0, we print '+' (ASCII 43), otherwise we decrement 'j'
// and print '-' (ASCII 45).
putchar(i++%4?--j,45:43);

// After the loop we print one more '+' and newline.
puts("+")

// The function declaration which takes the two input parameters, and
// also declares three integer variables. These three variables could
// also be declared as global variables with the same bytecount.
f(w,h,i,j,c)

// The start of the function body. We use the macro 'L' to print the 
// first line along with a newline.
{L;

// This loop prints all the lines between the first and the last. 'j'
// keeps track of when we should output a '+' instead of a '|'. 'h',
// which is the input parameter for height, serves as a terminator
// for the loop as it reaches zero.
for(j=1;h;<stuff missing from here>)

// We post-increment 'j' and check if its previous value is divisible
// by three, and if it isn't, we decrement 'h' and assign 124 (ASCII
// value for '|') to 'c'. Otherwise we assign '+' (ASCII 43) to 'c'.
c=j++%3?--h,124:43;

// The following is inside the 'increment' part of the 'for' loop.
// We print the character corresponding to the value of 'c', then
// the same character again, but padded with i-1  spaces before it 
// ('i' hasn't been touched since the first loop, so it still stores
// the length of the first line), then a newline.
printf("%c%*c\n",c,i,c)

// Lastly we print the first line again using the same macro 'L'.
L;}
```

Comment: Suggest `for(;h;printf("%c%*c\n",c,i,c=++j%3?--h,124:43));` instead of `for(j=1;h;printf("%c%*c\n",c,i,c))c=j++%3?--h,124:43;`

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>140</s> <s>137</s> <s>128</s> <s>119</s> <s>106</s> 105 bytes

```python
def f(w,h):a=~-w//3-~w;b=("+---"*w)[:a]+'+';print(b,*[i+' '*~-a+i for i in"||+"*h][:h+~-h//2],b,sep='\n')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcy7CoMwFADQvV9xyZLXvaS@KCh@iXVQakiWKCqEguTX06WT6xnO9j3dGqqcP4sFKyI62U59omhMRSl2cy@YJiKmohzaadRc827bfTjFjGrwmgNXiSbtwa47ePCBXZdmyo1D63QiZ0w54ozHsvX8HbjMVhQIhfwvjMnuYUWFUN6oQXjdqHgiNDerEWqZfw)

Comment: It's longer now but the issue has been fixed.

Comment: You could save a byte by removing the space between `in` and `[w+1+(w-1)//3]]` in the last part.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Nice first answer. :D

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can remove the space in `'\n') for` as well. Also, you can change `(w-1)` to `~-w`which allows you to remove the parentheses since unary operators have a higher precedence than binary ones. Same for `(h-1)` -> `~-h` and `(a-1)` -> `~-a`. [Try it online - 128 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc1LCsIwFEDRuat4ZJI/Mf0gtHQlMYOIlgQ0LbUQhNKtx4qz6vTC4Y6v2Q@xzH13znf3uFwdJOEbM04hzoQgLqVELFHTOMsxx4KZwDFgtkrHA/TDBAFCRMvCEfPWNJ6v0itVWPEHP29jh88R049zmzOJ6w0kpUprc0@0AE3b7xwh2h56UgoodqkWcNolfRRQ71oloPqVuqD5DQ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Also since all of your output is printed, `def f(w,h)` is the same length as `lambda w,h`, but allows you to use multiple lines if that helps you golf your code further

Comment: Thanks for the advice, everyone! @ovs should your code be a separate answer or do you think it would be better to replace this one?

Comment: @ovs The Python 3 code is now shorter anyway so never mind.

Comment: `a=~-w//3-~w;` to save 1 byte

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 38 bytes

37 bytes of code, +1 for `-n` flag.

```
Ph:'-Xa<>3JW'+PsX#h-2WR:'|Xb<>2J'+^xh
```

Takes width and height as command-line arguments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/IMNKXTci0cbO2CtcXTugOEI5Q9coPMhKvSYiycbOyEtdO64i4////7p5/03/mwMA)

#### Explanation

```
                         a,b are cmdline args; s is space; x is empty string (implicit)
Ph:'-Xa<>3JW'+
   '-Xa                  String of hyphens of length a
       <>3               grouped into substrings of (maximum) length 3
          JW'+           Join on +, also wrapping the result in +
 h:                      Assign that string to h (mnemonic: "header")
P                        and print it (with newline)

PsX#h-2WR:'|Xb<>2J'+^xh
          '|Xb           String of pipes of length b
              <>2        grouped into substrings of (maximum) length 2
                 J'+     joined on +
                    ^x   and split on empty string (i.e. converted to list of chars)
 sX#h-2                  String of len(h)-2 spaces
       WR:               Wrap the spaces with the list of chars
                         Note 1: WR operates itemwise on lists, so the result is a list,
                          each item of which consists of the spaces wrapped in an item
                          from the list of chars
                         Note 2: the : compute-and-assign meta-operator is here abused
                          to give WR: lower precedence than J and ^ and avoid parentheses
P                        Print that list, newline-separated (-n flag)
                      h  Autoprint the header a second time as the footer
```

Answer (score 4):

## Charcoal, <s>47</s> <s>45</s> 40 bytes

```
Ｆ⁴«¿﹪ι³ＦＩη↓⁺×+¬﹪κ²|ＦＩθ⁺×+¬﹪κ³-Ｐ+¿⁼ι¹Ｊ⁰¦⁰
```

Explanation: Works by drawing each side's `-`s/`|`s in turn, inserting `+`s where necessary, then finishing with a `+`. After drawing the top and right sides, jumps back to the start to draw them in reverse order, effectively drawing the left and bottom sides. I don't know whether rotational symmetry is permitted, but if so, then for <s>27</s> 25 bytes:

```
Ｆ⁴«ＦＩ⎇﹪ι²ηθ⁺×+¬﹪κ⁻³﹪ι²-⟲Ｔ
```

Takes the above idea to the extreme by drawing the top side, rotating left, drawing the right side, rotating again, and then repeating to draw the bottom and left sides in reverse.

Comment: @LeakyNun Last time I beat Pyth was for Double up some diamonds, and even then it was only just shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 165 bytes

```
v=Column;d[w_,y_,m_,n_]:=Table[If[Mod[i,y]==0&&i!=w,m,n],{i,w}];(a="+"<>d[#,3,"-+","-"]<>"+";b=v@d[#2,2,"|\n+","|"];v[{a,Row[{b,""<>Table[" ",#+Floor[#/3]],b}],a}])&
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>133</s> 132 bytes

```js
w=>h=>(a="-".repeat(w).replace(/--?-?/g,"+$&")+`+`)+(`
|`.padEnd(a.length)+`|`).repeat(h).replace(/(\|( +)\|\n)\1/g,`$&+$2+
`)+`
`+a
```

Takes input in currying syntax: `f(width)(height)`.

### Test Snippet

```js
f=
w=>h=>(a="-".repeat(w).replace(/--?-?/g,"+$&")+`+`)+(`
|`.padEnd(a.length)+`|`).repeat(h).replace(/(\|( +)\|\n)\1/g,`$&+$2+
`)+`
`+a
O.innerHTML=f(W.value=5)(H.value=10)
```

```html
<div oninput="O.innerHTML=f(+W.value)(+H.value)">
W <input id=W type=number min=1> H <input id=H type=number min=1>
</div>
<pre id=O>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 40 bytes

```
AQj++KjJj\+c*\-G3"++"m++d*lJ;dj\+c*\|H2K
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AQj%2B%2BKjJj%5C%2Bc%2a%5C-G3%22%2B%2B%22m%2B%2Bd%2alJ%3Bdj%5C%2Bc%2a%5C%7CH2K&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%2C1%0A3%2C2%0A5%2C7%0A10%2C5%0A4%2C4&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>178</s> 177 bytes

```java
w->h->{int i=0;String t="",m,r;for(;i<w;)t+=i++%3<1?"+-":"-";r=t+="+\n";m=t.format("|%"+(t.length()-3)+"s|\n","");for(i=0;i<h;)r+=i++%2<1&i>1?m.replace("|","+")+m:m;return r+t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDNbsIwEITvPMXKElVcJxaBVpVwEm5IPfTEse3BhYSYxk7kbEAI8uypCT/qDU4erb@ZWXsjtzIoq9RsVr@d0lVpETZuxhtUBc8as0RVGv4sBlXzU6glLAtZ1/AhlYHDAEAZTG0mlynM4QALtMqsIfPcGHb@6RZyKqB15MVfo0R3bEu1Au1SvLPn8xukXde0DwV4Nzi/dEf/9RlOEsjibhckeZAcTh0qHolLN8aE@Nq3IiutJ1S0ExRZrBgbTqJwRlhApiQgwsZuStiXIULHyB2sJXrkOCTMQ16kZo25R4MJZaQ@OsonhPaRpyoV5YLac@o4Cp9UEs40t2lVuI9wIY5mhDI91cKm2FgDlqFoO9G/bbGvMdW8bJBXbmUsjJdxWVXF3gvpTdC78OQKjx@AX6/w2wNwOKI32336hd5ED7eDtvsD)

-1 byte thanks to @KevinCruijssen

Comment: You can save a byte by currying the parameters: `w->h->` [Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jZDNbsIwEITveQrLElUsJxaBVpVwEm6VeuiJY9uDG5xgGjuWswEh4NlT8xNOleA2mv083p212Ii4sdKsl7@90rZxgNbeYx2ompWdKUA1hr1dBQ9s91OrAhW1aFv0IZTZBwi1IMCbA5W@G5CVdNE/zgKcMlWeoxJl/TbOV3G@VwaQysb8MkOQYRzpyPGycSFX6ZYToJmidDRNkzmmMZ7hGHOXeRfTL4O5zoB5WAsI8WGEaQislqaCVUjiKaG4PXgqwpicI09fqXTFibukTtLkSeXJXDMnbS0K6UM8TTGheqa5k9A5gxwFfux54M@9dnC9etOoJdK@ifCy/@c3Eq5qyakYhBa7FqRmTQfM@inUJiyZsLbehQm5CcLvwdMBnjwAvwzw6wNwMia3Z/fpZ3ITZ/gYHPs/)

Comment: Yep, I constantly forget about currying... It's not something I find natural :s

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>47 45</strike> 37 bytes

```
Ａ…+---÷⁺²×⁴Ｎ³αＡ…+||÷⁺¹×³Ｎ²βＰα↓βα+↖↑⮌β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9noWPGpZp6@rqHt7@qHHXoU2Hpz9q3PJ@z7pDm89thErW1EDkdh6efmgzSGrTuU3v92w4t/FR2@Rzm85t1H7UNu1R28RH63rObfr/39BAwRQA)

- 2 bytes saved after playing with the signs in the string creation.
- 8 bytes saved thanks to Neil, who came up with a much simpler way to calculate the lengths of the fences.

A different approach from [@Neil's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128754/70347): first I create the strings `α` and `β` containing the chars in the horizontal and vertical borders, using the `Range` operator that creates a repetition of a string until a given length is reached. Then I print them in the proper order:

- Print α without moving the cursor.
- Print β downwards.
- Print α.
- Print a "+".
- Move the cursor up and to the left.
- Print β upwards, reversed.

Link to a [verbose version](https://tio.run/##bczNCoJAFAXgfU8xuLqDM5Bam1wJboKKkHwAf242oOPgjLbx3acmKKHaHO7lcL7qVgxVX7TWJlqLRkJWyAbB8znnHiN7aVIxiRohqWsIGbmIDjVsXKNGcxq7EgeglDISuShovPqC5vnHCd5O9McJXZRP5zi2RqhBSAOOPb@uXdrfJSs//9J4vudG/YSwy9UBr2YZ5YplOOGgEUpKY2uDNdlaPlmu2wc).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about `Range`, that saves 3 bytes on my second approach!

Comment: @Neil that's nice because I have just outgolfed you and I just can't believe it. :-)

Comment: Better still, I managed to optimise your expressions, saving 8 bytes: `Ａ…+---÷⁺²×⁴Ｎ³αＡ…+||÷⁺¹×³Ｎ²βＰα↓βα+↖↑⮌β`.

Comment: @Neil Wow. Such optimization. Very Charcoal.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 58 bytes

```
D3/ó+DU'-×'+.ø©'|DXú«²D2/ó+.D®»'-4×D'+3ǝ.:¶¡ø'|3×D'+2ǝ.:ø»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fxVj/8GZtl1B13cPT1bX1Du84tFK9xiXi8K5Dqw9tcjECSeq5HFp3aLe6rsnh6S7q2sbH5@pZHdp2aOHhHeo1xmAhI5AQUOfu//9NuUwB)

Harder in 05AB1E than I thought.